# How to get the sum of values per day grouped by day from an array in DART / Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello how can I get the sum of isWatch property below the list of objects grouped by createdTime day ?

```
[
  {
    "videoId": 1,
    "videoName": "Test Video 1",
    "duration": 300,
    "createdTime": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z",
    "isWatch": 1,
  },
  {
    "videoId": 2,
    "videoName": "Test Video 2",
    "duration": 500,
    "createdTime": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z",
    "isWatch": 10,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edited for Amit Kumar's comment)

i think the shortest way is that:

```
    import "package:collection/collection.dart";

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> liste = [
    {
      "videoId": 1,
      "videoName": "Test Video 1",
      "duration": 300,
      "createdTime": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z",
      "isWatch": 1,
    },
    {
      "videoId": 2,
      "videoName": "Test Video 2",
      "duration": 500,
      "createdTime": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z",
      "isWatch": 10,
    },
    {
      "videoId": 2,
      "videoName": "Test Video 2",
      "duration": 500,
      "createdTime": "1969-07-21 20:18:04Z",
      "isWatch": 13,
    },
    {
      "videoId": 2,
      "videoName": "Test Video 2",
      "duration": 500,
      "createdTime": "1969-07-23 20:18:04Z",
      "isWatch": 12,
    },
    {
      "videoId": 2,
      "videoName": "Test Video 2",
      "duration": 500,
      "createdTime": "1969-07-23 20:18:04Z",
      "isWatch": 14,
    }
  ];

  _groupAndSum() {
    Map groupByDay =
        groupBy(liste, (obj) => DateTime.parse(obj['createdTime'].split(' ')[0])));

    Map groupedAndSum = Map();

    groupByDay.forEach((k, v) {
      groupedAndSum[k] = {
        'list': v,
        'sumOfisWatch': v.fold(0, (prev, element) => prev + element['isWatch']),
      };
    });

    print(groupByDay.toString());
    print(groupedAndSum.toString());
  }
```

and output will be:

```
flutter: {20: [{videoId: 1, videoName: Test Video 1, duration: 300, createdTime: 1969-07-20 20:18:04Z, isWatch: 1}, {videoId: 2, videoName: Test Video 2, duration: 500, createdTime: 1969-07-20 20:18:04Z, isWatch: 10}], 21: [{videoId: 2, videoName: Test Video 2, duration: 500, createdTime: 1969-07-21 20:18:04Z, isWatch: 13}], 23: [{videoId: 2, videoName: Test Video 2, duration: 500, createdTime: 1969-07-23 20:18:04Z, isWatch: 12}, {videoId: 2, videoName: Test Video 2, duration: 500, createdTime: 1969-07-23 20:18:04Z, isWatch: 14}]}

flutter: {20: {list: [{videoId: 1, videoName: Test Video 1, duration: 300, createdTime: 1969-07-20 20:18:04Z, isWatch: 1}, {videoId: 2, videoName: Test Video 2, duration: 500, createdTime: 1969-07-20 20:18:04Z, isWatch: 10}], sumOfisWatch: 11}, 21: {list: [{videoId: 2, videoName: Test Video 2, duration: 500, createdTime: 1969-07-21 20:18:04Z, isWatch: 13}], sumOfisWatch: 13}, 23: {list: [{videoId: 2, videoName: Test Video 2, duration: 500, createdTime: 1969-07-23 20:18:04Z, isWatch: 12}, {videoId: 2, videoName: Test Video 2, duration: 500, createdTime: 1969-07-23 20:18:04Z, isWatch: 14}], sumOfisWatch: 26}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps me.

Comment: This method will run two loops under the hood, while the method I posted will do the same work in one loop.

Comment: This only matches the day of the date which can be the same for two different months or maybe two different years. Thus this code produces the wrong result.

Comment: @AmitKumar i changed code for your comment and please check again if there is a problem

Comment: @SahilKumar the second loop for making group of videos those watched in a day

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this, don't be scared to use Generics.

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

Map<T, U> groupByListAndApply<T, U, V, W>(
    List<V> list,
    T Function(V) groupByGetter,
    W Function(V) mapItem,
    U Function(List<W>) applyFunction) {
  Map<T, List<V>> tmpMap = groupBy<V, T>(list, groupByGetter);
  return tmpMap.map((key, value) =>
      MapEntry(key, applyFunction(value.map((e) => mapItem(e)).toList())));
}

double sum(List<double> list) =>
    list.fold(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element);


List<Map<String,dynamic>> list = [
  {
    "videoId": 1,
    "videoName": "Test Video 1",
    "duration": 300,
    "createdTime": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z",
    "isWatch": 1,
  },
  {
    "videoId": 2,
    "videoName": "Test Video 2",
    "duration": 500,
    "createdTime": "1969-07-20 20:18:04Z",
    "isWatch": 10,
  }
];
Map<String, double> map = groupByListAndApply<String,double,Map<String,dynamic>,double>(
    list, (e) => (e["createdTime"] as String), (e) => (e["isWatch"] as int) *1.0, (e) => sum(e));
print('$map');
```

> //Results:
> {1969-07-20 20:18:04Z: 11.0}

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
void main() {
    final data = json.decode(
      "[{\"videoId\":1,\"videoName\":\"Test Video 1\",\"duration\":300,\"createdTime\":\"1969-07-20 20:18:04Z\",\"isWatch\":1},{\"videoId\":1,\"videoName\":\"Test Video 1\",\"duration\":300,\"createdTime\":\"1969-07-20 20:18:04Z\",\"isWatch\":50},{\"videoId\":1,\"videoName\":\"Test Video 1\",\"duration\":300,\"createdTime\":\"1969-07-21 20:18:04Z\",\"isWatch\":20}]");

  final map = HashMap<String, int>();
  for (var value in (data as List)) {
    if (map[value['createdTime']] == null) {
      map[value['createdTime']] = value['isWatch'];
    } else {
      map[value['createdTime']] = map[value['createdTime']] + value['isWatch'];
    }
  }

  print(map);
}
```

Checkout this dartPad sample : https://dartpad.dev/c071e4e0578ad0e2acdbe568a8326ae5

Comment: There are two problems; 1. this code don't  sum values of a day if the hours are different in a day. and 2 this code don't make a group of videos those watched in a day